# How could I Trace Gmail events(open next email,back to inbox, inbox to email) using chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How could I Trace Gmail events(open next email,back to inbox, inbox to email) using chorme extension?
I am developing a chorme extension from which I can create new user to my site,
What I have requried that, I will create I frame on the right side, and when user will click the email, all the information of the user on my site will be shown on the right box,
how I can do this
please help me out,

thanks in advance,
Saurabh

Comment: You can look at the URL to get an idea for what page the user is on. Otherwise, see if certain elements exist - the inbox, for example, won't have a reply box.